# download file from multiple thread in C#

Tags: c#

Imagine I have, mywebsite/1 .. until x. Now I'm trying to download 20images based on this method.
Why this is working when I have only 1 thread and don't working if I have more than 1 thread?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] names = new string[20];
            string[] urls = new string[20];

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                urls[i] = "http://www.mywebsite.fr/" + i;
                names[i] = (i + 1) + ".png";
                Links.Enqueue(urls[i]);
                Pathnames.Enqueue(names[i]);
            }
            List<Thread> TList = new List<Thread>();

            int index = 0;
            while (index < 20)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(DoWork);
                    t.IsBackground = true;

                    TList.Add(t);
                    TList[i + index].Start();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    TList[i + index].Join();
                index += 1;
            }
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            string url = null;
            //try
            //{
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0");
                    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                    //client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                    //client.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                    client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "euconsent-v2=CPG74goPG74goAKAeAENBcCsAP_AAH_AAAwIH3tf_X__bX9j-_59__t0eY1f9_7_v-wzjhfdt-8N2P_X_L0X42E7PF36pq4KuR4Eu3LBIQNlHOHUTUmw6okVrTPsak2Mr7NKJ7LEmnMZe2dYGHtfn91TuZKY7_78_9fz3_-v_v___9f3r-3_3__59X---_e_V399zLv9__3__9gfiASYal8AF2JY4Mk0aVQogQhWEh0AoAKKAYWiawgYXBTsrAI9QQMAEJqAjAiBBiCjFgEAAgEASERASAHggEQBEAgABACpAQgAImAQWAFgYBAAKAaFiBFAEIEhBkcFRymBARItFBPZWAJRd7GmEIZRYAUCj-iowEShBAsDISFg5gAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA");
                    client.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
                    client.Headers.Add("TE", "Trailers");

                    url = GetUrlImage(client.DownloadString(Links.Dequeue())); // here, when Links.Dequeue is used
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(url, "C:\\Users\\john\\source\\repos\\tst00\\tst00\\bin\\debug\\" + Pathnames.Dequeue());
                    }
                }
           // }
            //catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message + " / url: " + url);}
        }
```

If I set more than one threads, I get an error :

- System.ArgumentNullException
- HResult=0x80004003
- Message=La valeur ne peut pas être null. // Value cannot be null
- Nom du paramètre : address // name of param Source=System

Comment: *Don't* use the obsolete `WebClient` class. Create a single instance of `HttpClient` and use `client.GetStreamAsync()` as many times as needed to retrieve the files. What runtime are you using? .NET Core? .NET Framework? What language version?

Comment: What is the type of `Links`? If it is `Queue<string>` see the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-5.0#remarks) regarding multithreading.

Comment: Also read up on how to use `async` and `await`. The example you are working from is about 12-15 years old. Even 15 years ago, a good example would have used thread pool threads rather than managing threads the way your code does. If use modern `Task`-based code, you won't need threads at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the obsolete `WebClient` class and raw threads you can use HttpClient and asynchronous methods. The code becomes a lot simpler this way.

Assuming you use .NET 5, you can create a record to hold URL and file paths:

```
record Download( string Url,string Path);
```

And an asynchronous method to download the URL to the path :

```
async Task DownloadAsync(HttpClient client,Download dl)
{
    using var dlStream=await client.GetStreamAsync(dl.URL);
    using var fileStream=File.Create(dl.Path);
    await dlStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

You can now create an HttpClient instance and start downloading. HttpClient is thread-safe, so you can start multiple downloads concurrently.

Using a simple loop, you can download items one at a time.

```
var downloads=Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                        .Select(i=>new Download(
                             $"http://www.mywebsite.fr/{i}",
                             $"{i+1}.png");

var client=new HttpClient();

foreach(var dl in downloads)
{
    await Download(client,dl);
}
```

You can also start *all* downloads at once and await all of them to completet:

```
var tasks=downloads.Select(dl=>Download(client,dl));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

To set cookies, you need to create and pass an HttpClientHandler to the `HttpClient` constructor. Default headers can be set on the HttpClient instance :

```
var cookieContainer=new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(...));

var handler=new HttpClientHandler {
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer
};


var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
...
```